# Having trouble when connecting windows machine from windows machine

Tags: python, windows, server

I am trying to fetch the CPU usage of the windows server machine from the windows machine using python

Error

```
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Usage-script/connect.py", line 24, in <module>
    client.connect(hostname=host,port=port,  username=username, password=password)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 349, in connect
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\util.py", line 283, in retry_on_signal
    return function()
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 349, in <lambda>
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Code

```
import paramiko 
import psutil

def get_ram_usage(host, username, password):      
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()     
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())     
  ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)      
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('free -m')     
  ram_usage = psutil.virtual_memory().percent      
  return ram_usage


host = 'X.Y.Z.M' 
username = 'Administrator'
 password = '***********' 
port = 22  
client = paramiko.SSHClient()  
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client.connect(hostname=host,port=port, username=username, password=password)  
print("Connected to the server")
```

When I try to run this code it is showing this error. What is the reason for it?